# Using 16550D UART FIFO

Tags: c, linux, uart

I'm trying to make a UART_read function using the FIFO register, but I'm having trouble understanding how it works. I understand it allows me to get more characters per read, so it means read will interrupt the processor less times, but how exactly do I use it after enabling it? I can't find examples anywhere. My current function is:

```
unsigned char UART_read(void){
 unsigned int buf;
 while( ( ( inb(UART_LSR + UART) ) & UART_LSR_DR ) == 0 ){
         schedule();
 }
 buf = inb(UART);
 return (char)buf;
}
```

Comment: *"while( (inb(UART_LSR_DR)) == 0 )"* is not going to work as I commented in your other question. This code is testing garbage at I/O address 0x0001 where there are no UART registers (since UART_LSR_DR is probably 0x01, but is a bit mask and is not a register offset nor a port address).

Comment: I edited the code and now it seems to work well.

Comment: Relating to the statement in the while, not the FIFO, btw.

Answer (score 2):

I can direct you to two sources of information; the UART data sheets and Linux serial driver (drivers/tty/serial/8250/ directory within the Linux kernel source tree, and within that primarily the 8250.c source file).

One such UART data sheet is provided by Texas Instruments at http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/ns16c552

In Chapter 9 it has, in my opinion, a pretty good description of the FIFO mode operation. Basically, there are two types of interrupts for received data; one for when the amount of unread data in the receive fifo has reached a set threshold level (typically should be less than the FIFO size, to allow the OS some time to read the received characters before more data arrives), and another for the case when there's some data, but not enough to raise the "buffer full" alert sitting in the FIFO for some time. This latter is to let the OS pick up received single characters in a reasonable time.

When the OS receives these interrupts, it then typically should read as many characters from the FIFO as it can (using a status register bit to indicate whether there still is more data to read).

Similarly, when transmitting, the OS can write to the transmit FIFO until it receives an indication that the FIFO is full. The UART will later on generate an interrupt to tell that the transmit FIFO has some amount of room (again configurable) available.

Note though, that if you're writing your code as userspace code in Linux (i.e. as a regular application), you can't receive interrupts. On the other hand, if you're writing a driver of your own, you have to make sure it's your driver that claims the UART you're interacting with, instead of the default 8250.c UART driver.

Comment: After reading the datasheet, I know what the bits do in polled operation, which is what I want right now, but I still don't see how exactly the FIFO operates, as in, where do the characters go, and how can I access them.

Comment: The FIFO is read just as you would read with the non-FIFO operation. Just keep reading from the RX data inb port address.  
Without a FIFO, when you're done reading one character, you typically would exit the interrupt service routine, and only read more when the next RX interrupt is raised.  
With FIFO, you would loop on reading until the status shows that the FIFO is empty.  
Linux seems to additionally limit reading to 256 characters per interrupt, apparently to make sure the interrupt service routine isn't running for too long time at a single stretch.

Comment: Ok, so let me see if I'm closer to what I want. Let's assume I want to read 10 characters, for now without using interrupts. Assuming the above routine is correct, with FIFO enabled, it will read the ten characters, one per loop. I'm assuming then that every inb(UART + UART_RX) will need to be kept in an array, for example, for later use, seeing as the read is done the same way, FIFO or not. Do I need to check the status of FIFO to know when to stop reading or is it done automatically?

Comment: *"I want to read 10 characters ... without using interrupts"* - The the FIFO is less useful when not using interrupts.  Just poll the status and read as if there was no FIFO.

Comment: Even so, that doesn't answer my other question. If I just read as if there was no FIFO, what does the RX register give me? One character at a time and I have to manage an array to keep them, or something else?

Comment: One read gives you one character, FIFO or no FIFO. You'll need to read the status first to find out whether there's a new character available. If you read data in a situation where there's no new character available, the result of the read is undefined (if I remember correctly - but anyway it will not be any data you were expecting). And when you've read a character, it's up to you to decide what to do with it. In most cases you want to store it somewhere for some other part of the program to process it.

Comment: And another comment on the purpose of the FIFO; FIFOs appeared in UARTs when the transfer speeds rose so high that it often happened that an inbound character was overrun with the next one, as the computer wasn't fast enough in servicing the RX interrupt. So, characters were lost, requiring retransmissions, and thus affecting throughput.  
  
TX FIFOs helped to reduce CPU loads when transmitting characters at high speed; it became possible to send out several characters in a short burst, and then have the CPU available for other tasks for quite a good while.

Comment: Ok, so check to see if there is a character to be received and retrieve it. Without FIFO, I already have that working. But even after all these explanations, there's still something I don't get. Say I receive a burst of 10 characters, but in this case I have FIFO enabled and read from RX as if there was no FIFO. How does FIFO help me here? If RX still holds one character at a time, how does FIFO make sure I don't lose any characters?

Comment: Without FIFO, if you don't read a character by the time the next character has arrived, you lost the character you didn't read. In other words, your code has to be able to reliably check for new characters more frequently than new characters can arrive. With FIFO, you can have significantly longer interval between the checks, as overruns occur only after the FIFO has become full. Reading the 10 characters shouldn't be an issue - but being able to reliably read every single character one by one (so, without FIFO) at 38400 bits/s or at 115200 bits/s was an issue. With FIFO, it was manageable.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your register manual,

Usually, a FIFO register is 32bit long, but only a number of low bits are available or meaningful.

So you can get more characters by setting how many bits are available or meaningful in the 32bit long FIFO. There should have some place to set this.

Comment: That I get, but what is the code I need to write to and read from the appropriate registers? Or how does the FIFO registers catch the characters I want read?

Comment: *"Usually, a FIFO register is 32bit long"* - Please provide an example of a UART that has a *"32bit long FIFO"*.  Otherwise correct your "answer" or delete this erroneous post.